# How to cancel ProcessDialog from onPreExecute() method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-background

I have no idea how to return from `onPreExecute()` when some condition happens.
 for instance:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       if(varCancel){
         //Do not execute doInBackground() method
        }
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

the thing is, I want to cancel this process before the method `doInBackground()` start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) to cancel execution of Task.

```
   if(varCancel){
     //Do not execute doInBackground() method
       this.cancel(true);
    }
```

Or use class object which is used to call `execute()` for starting `AsyncTask` to cancel it:

```
   if(varCancel){
     //Do not execute doInBackground() method
       <CLASS_OBJECT>.cancel(true);
    }
```